# Cannot dismiss Android ProgressDialog

Tags: android, android-dialog

I have a static ProgressDialog object named **dialog** in my class

```
dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
```

This code is executed

`buildGroupAccessDialog(groupName);
 dialog.show(c, "Joining", "Please wait...");`

These are the methods involved

```
private void builGroupAccessDialog(final String groupName){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    // set title
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Join group");

    // set dialog message
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Do you want to join " + groupName + "  ?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //join group
                    joinGroup(groupName);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                }
            }).create()
            .show();

}
```

joinGroup() is invoked:

```
private void joinGroup(final String groupName) {
    Log.d("TRY TO JOIN GROUP:", groupName);


    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Get the device
            WifiP2pDevice dev = mRecyclerViewFragment.getDeviceMap().get(groupName);

            WifiP2pConfig config = new WifiP2pConfig();

            config.deviceAddress = dev.deviceAddress;


            wifip2pManager.connect(wifiDirectChannel, config, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Log.d("CONNECT", "SUCCESS");

                    // This is used for avoiding registering another BroadcastListener on purpose, keeping only one but responding
                    // to intent only when I'm sure I want it
                    iWantToConnect = true;

                    // Hide progress dialog
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int reason) {

                    Log.d("CONNECT", "FAILURE");

                    //Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "PIPPO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }
            });

        }
    }).start();

}
```

And i have 2 problems:

Please note that I'm talking about **dialog** variable

**1)** Progress Dialog starts without waiting user AlertDialog response (how to make this synchronous?)

**2)** Progress dialog is not dismissed (why?)

Thanks

**EDIT:** I've changed my code in this way:

`buildGroupAccessDialog(groupName);`

and:

```
private void joinGroup(final String groupName) {
    Log.d("TRY TO JOIN GROUP:", groupName);

    dialog.show(this, "Joining", "Please wait...");

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Get the device
            WifiP2pDevice dev = mRecyclerViewFragment.getDeviceMap().get(groupName);

            WifiP2pConfig config = new WifiP2pConfig();

            config.deviceAddress = dev.deviceAddress;


            wifip2pManager.connect(wifiDirectChannel, config, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Log.d("CONNECT", "SUCCESS");

                    // This is used for avoiding registering another BroadcastListener on purpose, keeping only one but responding
                    // to intent only when I'm sure I want it
                    iWantToConnect = true;


                    // Togli il dialog di progress
                    dialog.dismiss();


                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int reason) {

                    Log.d("CONNECT", "FAILURE");

                    //Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "PIPPO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

                    // Togli il dialog di progress
                    //dialog.dismiss();

                    // show failure to the user VANNO MESSI NEL BROIASCASTRECEIVER

                    // refresh peer list
                }
            });

        }
    }).start();
}

private void buildGroupAccessDialog(final String groupName) {

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            this);

    // set title
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Join group");

    // set dialog message
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Do you want to join " + groupName + "  ?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //join group
                    joinGroup(groupName);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                }
            }).create()
            .show();
}
```

Now Problem 1) is solved, but I still cannot dismiss the dialog.
Any ideas?

Comment: Your dialog is not canceable outside. There is no dismiss call for negative button and for failure method.

Comment: OK, an can this influence the flow of the program? What dialog are you talking about?

Comment: See the answers, they are pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem; looking at the ProgressDialog reference, I noticed that show is a static method. So i replaced

```
dialog = new ProgressDialog(this)
dialog.show(c, "Joining", "Please wait...");
```

With

```
dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Joining", "Please wait...", false, true);
```

This way the subsequent

```
dialog.dismiss()
```

Works as expected. Thanks for all your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

To dismiss dialog add  `dialog.dismiss();` statement after `joinGroup(groupName);`

```
    .setPositiveButton(
    "Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
     {
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        //join group
                        joinGroup(groupName);

                       // Add this line
                        dialog.dismiss();          
              }
     })
```

same for **setNegativeButton**

This will dismiss your dialog.

Comment: please read the beginning of my question, it has been modified to be more clear

Comment: @diningphil  are you able to connect means onSuccess getting executed or not??
I think your onFailure is executed and in that you haven't dismissed the dialog.. 
dismiss it in failure case also.

Comment: @diningphil  did you find the solution?

Comment: Not yet.. I'll let you know if I find something

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare your dialog outside like this:

```
AlertDialog dialog;

private void builGroupAccessDialog(final String groupName){
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
// set title
alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Join group");

// set dialog message
alertDialogBuilder
        .setMessage("Do you want to join " + groupName + "  ?")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                //join group
                dialog.show() //Show dialog here
                joinGroup(groupName);
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            }
        });

 dialog = alertDialogBuilder.create(); //Changed here


}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: dialog is a ProgressDialog, not an Alert one

Comment: You can try to make progress dialog invisible in the beginning then on onClick make it visible and whenever you want to dismiss just make it invisible

Comment: please read the beginning of my question, it has been modified to be more clear

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about alertDialog then try this :

```
.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
     alertDialogBuilder.dismiss();
   }
});
```

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: please read the beginning of my question, it has been modified to be more clear